# Publishing a previous major version to npm with no tag and avoiding latest

Tags: npm, npm-publish

Is there a best way to publish a previous major version of an npm package without adding a tag for it? Our current major version is 3.x (v3) so we `npm publish` that version to automatically give it the `latest` tag. When we publish updates to the `2.x` version (v2) we have to give it a tag so that it doesn't automatically grab the `latest` tag from v3.

We could do something like `previous`, though the meaning of that is subjective. Really we don't *need* a tag for v2 at all. Semver works great if people want to install v2. Is there a better solution to not add unnecessary tags than publishing it with a tag and adding a `postpublish` script that deletes the tag? (That sounds ridiculous as I write it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at [this comment from 2015](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10625#issuecomment-162106553), "Every publish must be associated with a dist-tag, by design." And I don't see a way to bypass the tag in the current code of [**libnpmpublish**](https://github.com/npm/libnpmpublish/blob/0b326f019ba88832a144f7c1a59dd9e2d3bef520/publish.js#L103-L104) and [**npm**](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/665a7bde900d7fbf46aca609b0b9c92b5508a3ea/lib/publish.js#L68), unfortunately.

Thus, I think you have the best options laid out already: publish under another tag, whether that tag is temporary or not.

---

However, if I could make a suggestion...

Instead of the subjective `previous` tag, you could consider publishing the previous versions under a tag called `v2`. This is a pattern that I've noticed the [Angular team](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core?activeTab=versions) uses for LTS releases, for example:

[image: @angular/core dist-tags]

While I think it's of minimal use to a consumer since they *could* just `npm install @angular/core@11` instead of `npm install @angular/core@v11-lts`, nonetheless it might be a cleaner approach to publish.